# I am looking at reducing the amount of "Places Of Interest" that is returned in the api call of a location

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox

when we make a location search for downtown nashville, tn. I am returned businesses, hotels, competitor restaurants.  We would like to control what types of POI are returned. I see in mapbox for unity there is a way to filter out the POIs that are returned, but how do we do that for our web, iOS and Android SDK.  Is this a dashboard setting?

just a location search so far looking for development help.

Comment: I've added the Unity tag to get you wider audience. How are you requesting the data?